# Python: How to add a dynamic column in table?

Tags: python, data-science

Currently my code creates a table with different columns (Title, Date, etc.) where the news of the Google News keywords can be found. For example, in my code you can see the keyword "Mcdonalds" in the first place. Let's assume that the first four rows of the table contain news about MCdonalds. Now I want there to be another column called Keyword, where next to the news about Mcdonalds there is always the keyword (Mcdonalds) from my code in every row about the news of Mcdonalds. The same should be possible for all keywords. If line 5-10 has messages about Burger King, the keyword Burger King should be in the column Keyword in line 5-10.

```
import ssl
import smtplib
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

googlenews = GoogleNews()
googlenews.set_encode('utf_8')
googlenews.set_lang('en')
googlenews.set_period('7d')

googlenews.get_news("Mcdonalds")
googlenews.get_news("Burger King")
googlenews.get_news("New York")

keys = googlenews.results()[0].keys()
Table = []

for row in googlenews.results():
    Table.append({'Keyword': row['??'], 'Title': row['title'], 'Date': row['date'], 'Link': row['link'], 'Source': row['site']})

import pandas as pd
from email.message import EmailMessage

df = pd.DataFrame(Table)
´´´
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you add more explanation to it. And also share what dataframe you currently have & what you want to achieve

Comment: Hi, thank for your support. I edited the question and add the dataframe, I hope it is clear right now :).